# Prove that $2|ab| \leq a^2 + b^2$ and $|a|+|b| \leq \sqrt {2}(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am having issues solving these problems:
I tried using $(|a|+|b|)^2 \geq 0$ and $(|a|-|b|)^2 \geq 0$ but I am having problems constructing the proof. I need to gain some intuition on how to proceed.

> Show that for $a,b\in (-\infty,+\infty)$,   the following inequalities apply:

a) $2|ab| \leq a^2 + b^2$

b) $|a|+|b| \leq \sqrt {2}(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: Use $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I need further clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) $0 \leq (|a|-|b|)^2 = |a|^2 -2|a||b|+|b|^2 = a^2 - 2|ab|+ b^2\Rightarrow 2|ab| \leq a^2+b^2 $

(b) by (a) we have $(|a| + |b|)^2 = a^2 + 2|ab| + b^2 \leq a^2+b^2+a^2 +b^2 = 2(a^2+b^2) \Rightarrow |a|+|b| \leq \sqrt {2(a^2+b^2)}$

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thanks a million!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: If I see a similar question on a test is there a certain formula i can use?

Comment: what do you mean by formula?

Comment: Well not a formula, some kind of template maybe?

Comment: Well, if I got you right, if something similar shows up on a test, try using these $(|a|+|b|)^2 \geq 0\ $ and $(|a| - |b|)^2 \geq 0$, so you may extract some properties out of it.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: In part (a) why isn't |b| squared? (a^2-2|ab|+|b|)

Comment: Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: that's a relief..

Answer (score 0):

The first inequality is just a special case of Young's inequality, which states for $a,b≥0\ $, $1< p < ∞ $, and $1/p + 1/q = 1$ , we have $ab ≤ \frac{(a^{p})}{p} + \frac{(b^{q})}{q}$. So for the inequality you wish to prove, we just have $p=q=2$ (which is called the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality).

The general case can be proved by using calculus - consider the area under the graph $u=t^{(p-1)}$. Hint: consider the area of the rectangle, $|ab|$, and compare it to the integral of $t^{(p-1)}$ between 0 and a, and $u^{(q-1)}$ between $0$ and $b$.